# Passing Data from a ViewController to a Collection Cell within a Table Cell

Tags: ios, swift3

This may be a little confusing, but i have a view controller that has a table view that contains a custom table cell and within this table cell, I have a collectionView with each cell holding a single image. I am trying to configure my collectionCell's image using the userToView variable seen below.

The delegate function below is where the table cell is being configured:

**OtherUserAccountViewController.swift**

```
class OtherUserAccountViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var userToView = User() 

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: photosCellReuseIdentifier) as! OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }
...

}
```

The delegate function below is where this image is being set:

**OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell.swift**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "otherUserPhotosCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! OtherUserPhotosCollectionViewCell
    //Configure cell with photo from parent ViewController
    return cell
}
```

My custom CollectionViewCell can be seen below:

**OtherUserPhotosCollectionViewCell.swift**

```
class OtherUserPhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

I have only really been getting accustomed to Swift & iOS development over the last couple weeks so any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: what does `userToView` variable contains? where are you getting the images from?

Comment: Correct, I will be using an array of UIimages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by assuming that you have `UIImage`s already available to you

**Assuming you have a single UICollectionViewCell**

In `OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell.swift`

```
var photoFromTableView: UIImage?    

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "otherUserPhotosCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! OtherUserPhotosCollectionViewCell
    //Configure cell with photo from parent ViewController
    if let photo:UIImage = photoFromTableView {
        cell.imageView.image = photo
    }
    return cell
}
```

In `OtherUserAccountViewController.swift`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: photosCellReuseIdentifier) as! OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.photoFromTableView = //Image you want to pass
    return cell
}
```

**Assuming you have multiple UICollectionViewCells**

In `OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell.swift`

```
var photosArray: [UIImage]?    

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "otherUserPhotosCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! OtherUserPhotosCollectionViewCell
    //Configure cell with photo from parent ViewController
    if let photo_array:[UIImage] = photosArray {
        cell.imageView.image = photo_array[IndexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

In `OtherUserAccountViewController.swift`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: photosCellReuseIdentifier) as! OtherUserPhotosTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.photosArray = //Array of Images you want to pass
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!